# CockroachDB INNER JOIN UPDATE not working

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, cockroachdb

I am trying to implement CockroachDB INNER JOIN update, however it says following

```
HINT: You have attempted to use a feature that is not yet implemented.
```

Any thoughts?
The query is below:

```
UPDATE products 
SET products.prodname = 'Hello' 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN prodcategory 
ON products.categoryid  = prodcategory.prid 
WHERE products.productid = '9680ead9-57f6-441d-af5f-a384a66d3300';
```

Comment: What version of CockroachDB?  Why not `UPDATE products  SET products.prodname = 'Hello'  WHERE products.productid = '9680ead9-57f6-441d-af5f-a384a66d3300';` ?

Comment: Hi Adrian
Even this is not working.
I could do only SET prodname = 'Hello', however I do need this to be as a 1 query, due to an API, so users with one call could update all details on the fly.
Version of Cockroach is 22.1

Comment: It was a stupid on my part, `SET products.prodname = 'Hello' ` should be `SET prodname = 'Hello'` per [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html): *Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid.*.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE products 
SET products.prodname = 'Hello'
WHERE products.categoryid IN (
 SELECT prodcategory.prid
 FROM prodcategory
)
AND products.productid = '9680ead9-57f6-441d-af5f-a384a66d3300';
```

Comment: If you want to reference a field in prodcategory, you can do something like this:

Comment: EXISTS() usually scales much more efficiently than IN()

Comment: If you want to reference a field in prodcategory, you can do something like this:
```
UPDATE products 
SET products.prodname = prodcategory.somefield
FROM prodcategory 
ON products.categoryid  = prodcategory.prid 
WHERE products.productid = '9680ead9-57f6-441d-af5f-a384a66d3300';
```

Comment: Don't add these as comments, please edit your answer and add them there.

Comment: invalid syntax: statement ignored: at or near "prodname": syntax error: unimplemented: this syntax
SQLSTATE: 0A000
DETAIL: source SQL:
UPDATE products 
SET products.prodname = 'Hello'
             ^
HINT: You have attempted to use a feature that is not yet implemented.
See: https://go.crdb.dev/issue-v/27792/v22.1